# Dynamic-DynamoDB issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm having difficulty getting Dynamic-DynamoDB up and running.

I'm using the ec2 instance created with the supplied CloudFormation template.  The latest issue I'm having is this error:

```
    [ec2-user@ip-10-91-185-45 dynamic-dynamodb]$ sudo service dynamic-dynamodb start
2014-03-30T21:14:19.505657140: do_start:Firstly, uploading latest config file to S3
upload: ../etc/dynamic-dynamodb/dynamic-dynamodb.conf to s3://DynamicDynamoDB/config/dynamic-dynamodb.conf
2014-03-30T21:14:21.081230960: do_start:Starting dynamicdynamodb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/dynamic-dynamodb", line 22, in <module>
    import dynamic_dynamodb
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/dynamic_dynamodb/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from dynamic_dynamodb.core import dynamodb, gsi, table
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/dynamic_dynamodb/core/dynamodb.py", line 12, in <module>
    from dynamic_dynamodb.log_handler import LOGGER as logger
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/dynamic_dynamodb/log_handler.py", line 25, in <module>
    import config_handler
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/dynamic_dynamodb/config_handler.py", line 4, in <module>
    CONFIGURATION = config.get_configuration()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/dynamic_dynamodb/config/__init__.py", line 121, in get_configuration
    __check_gsi_rules(configuration)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/dynamic_dynamodb/config/__init__.py", line 318, in __check_gsi_rules
    if gsi['sns_message_types']:
KeyError: 'sns_message_types'
2014-03-30T21:14:21.256146861: Failed in starting dynamicdynamodb service
```

I'm using a configuration file that is based pretty much on the sample: a single table and a single GSI.  In the file sns is not enabled in either configuration.

Any idea where could be wrong?

On a side note, it's also not actually logging to the /var/logs directory as is configured in the conf file.  It's writing a log to ./logs where the conf file is located.  It's almost as if it's not actually reading the conf file properly.

Comment: AWS uses SNS with Dynamo DB to send alarm notifications when the table's request rate exceeds a certain amount. According to the example dynamo.conf file here: https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/dynamic-dynamodb/latest/dynamic-dynamodb.pdf SNS is configured to send notificatons in the config file. Can you post your config file?

Comment: I did actually, finally figure this out.  Keep trying things until it finally works.  The problem... the sample config has the line "sns-message-types" commented out.  Apparently, this is not a valid configuration.  Pretty disappointing to find an application with a sample configuration that is invalid.  
# sns-message-types: scale-up, scale-down

Answer (score 0):

This error was caused by an invalid setting in the sample configuration.  You must uncomment the sns-message-types line.

Comment: Found a ticket this morning about this topic: https://github.com/sebdah/dynamic-dynamodb/issues/135